# How to pass "like" or "Contains" parameters to fetchXML in ssrs report

Tags: .net, xml, crm, fetch, fetchxml

I tried to pass parameter to fetch XML for generating report.

It works fine for "Text Equals" field. But does not works for "Contains" .

I tried this but it doest work.

```
<condition attribute="new_owner_lead" operator="like" value="@ParameterName"  />
```

also tried this

```
value='%"+@ParameterName+"%'
value='%@ParameterName%'
```

but it doesnt work..
Can Any one suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what the condition should be:

```
<condition attribute="new_owner_lead" value="%TEST%" operator="like"/>
```

In you case you can use something like:

```
var fetchXml = 
    $"<filter type='and'>
        <condition attribute='new_owner_lead' value='%{ParameterName}%' operator='like'/>
   </filter>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Go into the properties of the dataset and click on the Parameters "tab".  Enter the following for your parameter value: ="%" & Parameters!myParameter.Value & "%"

Then use the standard value for a parameter in the condition value:

Comment: I am getting this error with this approach.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bu0qS.png

Answer (score 1):

Go into the Properties of the Dataset (Make sure you don't go to the Parameters section)  (See image below) and click on the Parameters "tab". Enter the following for your Parameter value:

`="%" & Parameters!myParameter.Value & "%"`

where myParameter is your variable, so yours will be different here.

Then use the standard value for a parameter in the condition value:

```
<filter type="and">
   <condition attribute="XXXXXXXXXX" operator="like" value="@myParameter" />
</filter>
```

[image]

Comment: I am getting this error with this approach.


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bu0qS.png